# Camel interceptFrom when stopped Message is consumed from broker

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to check one dynamic condition before my actual route is started.

Actual Route:

```
from("activemq:queue:testQueue").routeId("testQueue").to("mock:abc");
```

My Interceptor for above Route:

```
interceptFrom().when(header("name").isEqualTo("ramden")).stop();
```

So my question is when the message is published to the `testQueue` with the header as name and value as ramden first the interceptor kicks and stops the route when the condition is true. But the message is consumed by the application and dequeued from the broker. I need the message sent back to the broker whne the route is stopped in the interceptor. the application should not consume the message.

Comment: So are you saying that when some "special message" is posted to the queue, you want the Camel route to stop consuming from this queue, and that "special" message should be left untouched on the queue?

Comment: @Claus Ibsen  the message should be sent back to the queue and later that message should be consumed, I just hardcoded the header name value to ramden, this is dynamically updated. So that the message is later consumed and processed.

Comment: You could use the same interceptor to put the message in the queue, which will mean that the message will not be the exact same message (because you did a destructive get).